# Camera preview and Camera capture Use Camera2 API, But occur ;Request targets Surface that is not part of current capture session' message on android

Tags: android

I want Camera preview and Camera Capture use Camera2 API.

this code is works, but there is one problem.

problem is When click the capture button, capture succeeds, camera preview stops.

if I press the capture button again, the camera preview is still paused.

if I do not press the capture button after running the app, camera preview is success work.

`Error log` when the capture button is pressed.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: submitRequestList:208: Request targets Surface that is not part of current capture session
      at android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager.throwAsPublicException(CameraManager.java:650)
      at android.hardware.camera2.impl.ICameraDeviceUserWrapper.submitRequestList(ICameraDeviceUserWrapper.java:86)
      at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.submitCaptureRequest(CameraDeviceImpl.java:935)
      at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.setRepeatingRequest(CameraDeviceImpl.java:974)
      at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraCaptureSessionImpl.setRepeatingRequest(CameraCaptureSessionImpl.java:243)
      at com.bilal.androidthingscameralib.CameraHelper$4.onCaptureCompleted(CameraHelper.java:273)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at android.hardware.camera2.dispatch.InvokeDispatcher.dispatch(InvokeDispatcher.java:39)
      at android.hardware.camera2.dispatch.HandlerDispatcher$1.run(HandlerDispatcher.java:65)
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
   Caused by: android.os.ServiceSpecificException: submitRequestList:208: Request targets Surface that is not part of current capture session (code 3)
      at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2018)
      at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1950)
      at android.hardware.camera2.ICameraDeviceUser$Stub$Proxy.submitRequestList(ICameraDeviceUser.java:334)
      at android.hardware.camera2.impl.ICameraDeviceUserWrapper.submitRequestList(ICameraDeviceUserWrapper.java:84)
      at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.submitCaptureRequest(CameraDeviceImpl.java:935) 
      at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.setRepeatingRequest(CameraDeviceImpl.java:974) 
      at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraCaptureSessionImpl.setRepeatingRequest(CameraCaptureSessionImpl.java:243) 
      at com.bilal.androidthingscameralib.CameraHelper$4.onCaptureCompleted(CameraHelper.java:273) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
      at android.hardware.camera2.dispatch.InvokeDispatcher.dispatch(InvokeDispatcher.java:39) 
      at android.hardware.camera2.dispatch.HandlerDispatcher$1.run(HandlerDispatcher.java:65) 
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

and my source (MainActivity.class);

```
private InitializeCamera mInitializeCamera;
TextureView mTextureView;
ImageView imgCaptureImage;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Button capBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.capBtn); //capture button
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
         mInitializeCamera.captureImage();
       }
}
//camera open texture
private final TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener mSurfaceTextureListener 
        = new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
        mInitializeCamera = new InitializeCamera(getApplicationContext(), mOnPictureAvailableListener, mTextureView, 640, 480, 1); 
    }
    ...
};

//picture taken
private OnPictureAvailableListener mOnPictureAvailableListener = 
        new OnPictureAvailableListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPictureAvailable(byte[] imageBytes) {
                onPictureTaken(imageBytes);
            }
        };

//get picture
private void onPictureTaken(final byte[] imageBytes) {
    if (imageBytes != null) {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.length);
        imgCaptureImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```

(InitializeCamera.class) :)

```
OnPictureAvailableListener mOnPictureAvailableListener;
private HandlerThread mCameraHandlerThread;

//Initialize camera library class
private CameraHelper mCameraHelper;

//Handler for running Camera Task in the background
private Handler mCameraHandler = new Handler();

public InitializeCamera(Context mContext, OnPictureAvailableListener mOnPictureAvailableListener, TextureView textureView, int imageHeight, int imageWidth, int maxSize) {

   this.mOnPictureAvailableListener = mOnPictureAvailableListener;

   //create new handler thread for camera operations.
   mCameraHandlerThread = new HandlerThread("CameraBackground");
   mCameraHandlerThread.start();

   //Initialize Camera class.
   mCameraHelper = CameraHelper.getInstance();

   mCameraHelper.initializeCameraHelper(mContext, mCameraHandler, textureView, this, imageHeight, imageWidth, maxSize);
}

//capture image
public void captureImage() {
   mCameraHelper.takePicture();
}

//get imagereader available
@Override
public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {

   Image image = reader.acquireNextImage();

   ByteBuffer imageBuf = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
   final byte[] imageBytes = new byte[imageBuf.remaining()];
   image.close();

   //post image bytes data to main UI Thread for displaying it in image view
   mCameraHandler.post(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run()( {
           mOnPictureAvailableListener.onPictureAvailable(imageBytes);
       }
   });
}
```

(CameraHelper.class) (thanks)

```
TextureView textureView;
private CameraDevice mCameraDevice;
private CameraCaptureSession mCaptureSession;

private ImageReader mImageReader;
Size imageDimension;

private CaptureRequest.Builder captureRequestBuilder;

//Lazy-loaded singleton, so only one instance of the camera is created.
private CameraHelper() {
}

private static class InstanceHolder {
    private static CameraHelper mCamera = new CameraHelper();
}

public static CameraHelper getInstance() {
   return InstanceHolder.mCamera;
}

//Initialize the camera device.
public void initializeCameraHelper(Context context, Handler backgroundHandler, TextureView textureView, ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener imageAvailableListener, int imageWidth, int imageHeight, int maxImages) {

   this.textureView = textureView;

   //discover the camera instance
   CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
   String[] camIds = {};

   try {
        camIds = manager.getCameraIdList();
   if (camIds.length < 1) {
       return;
   }

   String id = camIds[0];
   CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(id);

   StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);

   imageDimension = map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class)[2];

   //Initialize the image processor
   mImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(imageWidth, imageHeight, ImageFormat.JPEG, maxImages);
   mImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(
           imageAvailableListener, backgroundHandler);

   //Open camera resource
   manager.openCamera(id, mStateCallback, backgroundHandler);
  } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
  }
}

/**
 * Callback handling device state changes
 */
private final CameraDevice.StateCallback mStateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onOpened(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Opened camera.");
        mCameraDevice = cameraDevice;
        createCameraPreview();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Camera disconnected, closing.");
        closeCaptureSession();
        cameraDevice.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice, int i) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Camera device error, closing.");
        closeCaptureSession();
        cameraDevice.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClosed(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Closed camera, releasing");
        mCameraDevice = null;
    }
};

private void createCameraPreview() {
    Log.d(TAG, "createCameraPreview --" + textureView);
    try {
        SurfaceTexture texture = textureView.getSurfaceTexture();

        texture.setDefaultBufferSize(imageDimension.getWidth(), imageDimension.getHeight());

        Surface surface = new Surface(texture);

        captureRequestBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
        captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface);

        mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(surface), new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
                if (mCameraDevice == null) {
                    return;
                }

                mCaptureSession = session;
                updatePreview();
            }

            @Override
            public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {

            }
        }, null);

    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

//ready preview screen
private void updatePreview() {
    if (mCameraDevice == null) {

    }

    captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
    try {
        mCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(captureRequestBuilder.build(), null, null);
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
/**
 * Begin a still image capture
 */
public void takePicture() {
    if (mCameraDevice == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Cannot capture image. Camera not initialized.");
        return;
    }
    // Here, we create a CameraCaptureSession for capturing still images.
    try {
        mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(
                Collections.singletonList(mImageReader.getSurface()),
                mSessionCallback,
                null);
    } catch (CameraAccessException cae) {
        Log.d(TAG, "access exception while preparing pic", cae);
    }
}

/**
 * Callback handling session state changes
 */
private CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback mSessionCallback =
        new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                // The camera is already closed
                if (mCameraDevice == null) {
                    return;
                }
                // When the session is ready, we start capture.
                mCaptureSession = cameraCaptureSession;
                triggerImageCapture();
            }

            @Override
            public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Failed to configure camera");
            }
        };

/**
 * Execute a new capture request within the active session
 */
private void triggerImageCapture() {
    try {
        final CaptureRequest.Builder captureBuilder =
                mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
        captureBuilder.addTarget(mImageReader.getSurface());
        captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON);
        Log.d(TAG, "Capture request created.");
        mCaptureSession.capture(captureBuilder.build(), mCaptureCallback, null);
    } catch (CameraAccessException cae) {
        Log.d(TAG, "camera capture exception");
    }
}

/**
 * Callback handling capture session events
 */
private final CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback mCaptureCallback =
        new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCaptureProgressed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session,
                                            @NonNull CaptureRequest request,
                                            @NonNull CaptureResult partialResult) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Partial result");
            }

            @Override
            public void onCaptureCompleted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session,
                                           @NonNull CaptureRequest request,
                                           @NonNull TotalCaptureResult result) {
                //session.close();
                //mCaptureSession = null;
                captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER_CANCEL);
                try {
                    mCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(captureRequestBuilder.build(), mCaptureCallback, null);    //OCCUR ERROR LOG
                } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "CaptureSession closed");
            }
        };
```

Occur error log CameraHelper.class

`Request targets Surface that is not part of current capture session`

```
private final CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback mCaptureCallback = 
        new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onCaptureCompleted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session,
                                           @NonNull CaptureRequest request,
                                           @NonNull TotalCaptureResult result) {
                //session.close();
                //mCaptureSession = null;
                captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER_CANCEL);
                try {
                    mCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(captureRequestBuilder.build(), mCaptureCallback, null);
                } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "CaptureSession closed");
            }
        };
```

this part

I think after capture, there seems to be a problem with `mCaptureCallback`

How to fix this problem?

if you know please advice for me..

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a new capture session in takePicture with just the one ImageReader Surface; after that, you can no longer use the TextureView Surface as a capture request target.  You have to create yet another session to resume preview.

It's better to just add the JPEG ImageReader Surface to the initial capture session, and not have to be continually tearing down sessions to take pictures (which is quite slow).  For regular preview, don't target the ImageReader in the repeating request, and then for still capture, just issue a capture request that targets the ImageReader.

See the [camera2basic](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2basic/Camera2BasicFragment.java) sample for examples of this.

Comment: First, I wolud like to thank you.  you say, just the one imageReader surface is `mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(
                    Collections.singletonList(mImageReader.getSurface()),
                    mSessionCallback,
                    null);`   is right?

Comment: and if I want resume preview, I create another session.

Comment: where is the initial capture session? `and then for still capture, just issue a capture request that targets the ImageReader.`    what is mean?

Comment: You create a capture session in createCameraPreview, and then replace it with a new session in takePicture. But you never recreate the preview capture session after that, causing the error.   What I suggest you do is pass two Surfaces to the preview session, and don't create a new one in takePicture.  Keep the same capture requests.

Comment: so I try, `mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(surface, mImageReader.getSurface), mSessionCallback, null);` on `CreateCameraPreview`

Comment: but occur `E/CameraDeviceClient: endConfigure: Camera 0: Unsupported set of inputs/outputs provided
 W/CameraDevice-JV-0: Stream configuration failed due to: endConfigure:372: Camera 0: Unsupported set of inputs/outputs provided
 E/CameraCaptureSession: Session 0: Failed to create capture session; configuration failed
 W/CameraHelper: Failed to configure camera`     faile camera preview.

Comment: I don't know what sizes you're trying to use; generally a single preview-resolution output plus a single high-resolution JPEG output should work, though.

Comment: I do not care what resolution you use,